# Load Custom Property in Identity Core

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-identity

I have created a class with custom property which inherits from IdentityUser class.

```
public class AppUser:IdentityUser
{
    public AppUser(string userName) : base(userName)
    {
        this.UserName = userName;
    }

    public AppUser()
    {

    }

    public string  FirstName { get; set; }
    public string  LastName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public List<UserAttribute> Attributes { get; set; }

}

public class UserAttribute
{
    [Key]
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

When I use,

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
```

It is not loading the values on Attributes property.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use claims instead of attributes?

Comment: We want to use these data for external use. And need to use certain table structure.

Comment: You'll have to include the Attributes in the query since ef core is lazy loading. Something like `userManager.Users.Include("Attributes").Where();`

Answer (score 0):

You should share the code for `_userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);`. I do believe that you are not loading the related data tho. Something like this should work for you:

```
using (var context = new YouDBContext())
{
    var user = context.Users
        .Where(user => user.UserName == userName)
        .Include(user => user.Attributes)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

Here the link for the documentation: [Loading Related Data.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)